# offline / Online Search Engine

Tags: php

Is there a simple php code that works with a html search form  that can read an offline file into a string and search for specific words in that file  and link the result  to as a weblink to an  online website with the file included, by using the search results from the offline file.

Comment: Yes there certainly is code to do that.

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Looks like you need to learn more about what is expected of users here. I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](//codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.